# Spatial predicates with Hibernate 5 ORM

Tags: hibernate, maven, hibernate-5.x, hibernate-spatial

I´m migrating an existing application from Hibernate 3.6.10.Final (with hibernate-spatial 1.1.1) to [Hibernate 5 ORM](http://hibernate.org/orm), which is supposed to include spatial capabilities. Therefore, I removed the reference to `org.hibernatespatial` in the pom.xml and upgrade 3.6.10.Final so that I'll have :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Where before I'd have queries created with spatial criteria, I get compilation errors as if it wouldn't find certain classes. For example, before I'd have something like :

```
import org.hibernatespatial.criterion.SpatialRelateExpression;
import org.hibernatespatial.criterion.SpatialRestrictions;

SpatialRelateExpression geomExpression = SpatialRestrictions.within("geom", area);
criteria.add(geomExpression);
```

Eclipse will raise that *"SpatialRelateExpression cannot be resolved"* (same for `SpatialRestrictions`. Even though I thought it would be enough to change the imports to these :

```
import org.hibernate.spatial.criterion.SpatialRelateExpression;
import org.hibernate.spatial.criterion.SpatialRestrictions;
```

And again Eclipse will complain that *"The import org.hibernate.spatial cannot be resolved"*. When I open the `hibernate-core-5.0.4.Final.jar` and `hibernate-entity-manager-5.0.4.Final.jar` libraries I can't find an `org.hibernate.spatial` package, but according to [Hibernate 5 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/spatial/SpatialRelation.html) about those spatial related classes I'd expect them to be ther.

I tried to Google for this, but maybe because Hibernate 5 has not been in the market for such a long time, I constantly get references to Hibernate 4.

My questions are :

- Do I need to change anything in my pom.xml and Maven dependencies to have spatial capabilities available? I expected them to be fully integrated in Hibernate main library.
- Should I make any substantial changes to my spatial query criteria in order to work with Hibernate 5? I couldn't find good examples out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the [`hibernate-spatial`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-spatial) dependency. It is not being pulled as transitive dependency from `hibernate-entitymanager`.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The documentation that you linked to is the documentation of all Hibernate modules combined, not just the core.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I got confused with that idea about merging both projects, which didn't necessarily meant merging both jars. And then by the Maven dependencies as they appear on their website : http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/